# wpf lable text binding not working, where i am going wrong

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding

I am new to WPF and trying something like this to update a label text in the WPF form from the class.
The onchange event is getting triggered, but not getting displayed on the form

Here is my class

```
Public Class ExtractDetails
Inherits UserControl
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Private _prdFrstName as string
Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Public Property PrdFrstName() As String
    Get
        Return _prdFrstName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        If _prdFrstName <> value Then
            _prdFrstName = value
            Me.OnPropertyChanged("PrdFrstName")
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub suMainStrt()
    PrdFrstName = strComurl     ''contyains teh URL to nagigate to
    webBrwFrst = New WebBrowser
    webBrwFrst.Navigate(New Uri(strComurl))
    Call extract(webBrwFrst, strComurl)
end sub
```

end class

the url keeps on changing as i ma getting the values from an excel file and looping for each URL.
i wanted to display the URL currently working now

this is my XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Avenet Prduct Description Extractor" Height="396.627" Width="588.123" Background="AliceBlue" Icon="LGIcon.ico">
<Grid Height="341.077" Width="567.721" Background="AliceBlue">

<StackPanel Margin="170.225,226.418,3.143,0" Name="StackPanel1" Height="97.994" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Label Height="30.906" Name="lblCrntSt1" Content="{Binding Path=PrdFrstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="161" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="AliceBlue" Background="Red" Foreground="White" FontSize="13"></Label>

    </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

and this is my windows class.

```
 Class Window1
 Dim clsIniti As New ExtractDetails
 Public Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    'clsIniti = New ExtractDetails
    Me.DataContext = clsIniti
 End Sub    
 end class
```

without updating the text labels the entire function is working good. but i wish to display few things. where i am going wrong

I tried data binding by removing few parts to new created project. it works there. so some thing wrong in this code??? :`(

Comment: How is your strComurl is being set? or How do you call subMainStrt function?

Comment: that mainstrt function is called on button click

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible causes that this doesn't work for you.

A. How does your OnPropertyChanged method look like?

```
' Correct implementation:
Private Sub OnPropertyChanged(propertyName As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
End Sub
```

B. Make sure the ExtractDetails instance you call suMainStrt on, is the same as your DataContext instance. Test this by calling suMainStrt directly from the constructor of Window1:

```
Class Window1
    Dim clsIniti As New ExtractDetails
    Public Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        'clsIniti = New ExtractDetails
        Me.DataContext = clsIniti

        ' test (if this works, your problem is B.)
        clsIniti.suMainStrt()
    End Sub    
End Class
```

As a side note: Unless you have good reasons to do this, I suggest you create a dedicated viewmodel (class, not usercontrol) that contains the properties you want to bind to.

Comment: thank you very much, but i am calling the suMainStrt function on button click and it gets initialized. and works. that OnPropertyChanged method is same. it is even triggered when the values change. but due to some reason it is not updated in the WPF form.

Comment: Thank you very much adabyron. as you mentioned it was point B.
 i had created an instance of class in the first(assume CLsA) and again was recreating another instant in the button click(CLsB) and was accessing the first class (CLsA) in to update values. your answer made me look into that. tanks a lot. i wasted one entire day for this extra line :( thank you very much

Comment: Glad you could sort it out. Please mark my answer as the accepted one, if you feel it deserves that.